# Basic Aurelia Project has Error: Expected ; in app.js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, aurelia

I expect this has something to do with the babel, es7 something or other.

This line of code is showing `Expected ';'` in visual studio

```
export class App {
    configureRouter(config, router) { /// <== here is the error
        this.router = router;
        config.title = 'Aurelia';
        config.map([
          { route: ['', 'home'],       name: 'home',       moduleId: 'home/index' },
          { route: 'users',            name: 'users',      moduleId: 'users/index',   nav: true },
          { route: 'users/:id/detail', name: 'userDetail', moduleId: 'users/detail' },
          { route: 'files/*path',       name: 'files',      moduleId: 'files/index',   href:'#files',   nav: true }
        ]);
    }
}
```

I created the project with all default options, so it is using babel.I thought this syntax is pretty common. Here is my config.js.

```
transpiler: "babel",
  babelOptions: {
    "optional": [
      "runtime",
      "optimisation.modules.system",
      "es7.decorators",
      "es7.classProperties"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: your es6 is correct... probably VS issue

Comment: when i've run into this, the error usually occurs well before the listed line. so if you have bad syntax 50 lines ago, it might only crop up 50 lines later, especially when its a curly brace or semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using ReSharper, try changing typescript options in ReSharper.
Go to ReSharper->Options->Code Editing->TypeScript->Inspections, and then set the desired version of the TypeScript.

[image]